# Matching certificates and private key in Keychain with .p12 file

Tags: ios, macos, keychain, ad-hoc-distribution

I have many certificates in my keychain, Then I add a new certificate from .p12 file, But I can't figure out where it is gone and which certificate is the one that I have added recently in the keychain.

Is there any way to match the certificate or private key with my .p12 files.?

Answer (score 0):

you could probably identify it by the expiry date of the certificate shown at the right end of the Keychain. (Of course if you cannot by the Certificate name alone)

Comment: If I have only .p12 how can I get expiry date from .p12?